# Is it possible to collect personal data of users Facebook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

There is an application with the integration of Facebook. Is it possible to collect the information of users who logged in through Facebook (thus allowed access to the application in your account) and transfer it to your own server for the target audience and further development of the application?

Comment: If I found out an app was doing this I would remove it so fast. This is bad very very bad. Unless you have the users permission to take that data you can not take anything.

Comment: @Popeye: If the application uses FB Login, the user **does** actually give permissions to use his data. What you as an app can do with it is defined in the FB Platform Policies. See https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data for example.